# How to go to another page from a sheet view in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink

I am trying to goto another page from a sheet view. Here is the code for the first view:

```
struct FirstView: View {
    @State fileprivate var isShowingSheet: Bool = false

    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            isShowingSheet = true
        }) {
            Text("Show the sheet")
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $isShowingSheet, content: {
            SecondView()
        })
    }
}
```

And here is the code for the second view:

```
struct SecondView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationLink(destination: ThirdView()) {
            Text("Show the third view.")
        }
    }
}
```

The Problem is that the third view will also be in that sheet. Is it possible to make the third view a normal page instead of a view in a sheet?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NavigationLink` should be in same view hierarchy of `NavigationView` to work, but `.sheet` introduces another different view hierarchy, so the solution would be to leave (hidden) navigation link in previous view, but activate it programmatically from view in sheet.

Here is a demo (tested with Xcode 12 / iOS 14)

```
struct FirstView: View {
    @State fileprivate var isShowingSheet: Bool = false
    @State private var showThirdView = false

    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            isShowingSheet = true
        }) {
            Text("Show the sheet")
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $isShowingSheet, content: {
            SecondView(showNext: $showThirdView)
        })
        .background(
              NavigationLink(destination: ThirdView(), isActive: $showThirdView) {
                    EmptyView()
              }
        )
    }
}

struct SecondView: View {
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    @Binding var showNext: Bool

    var body: some View {
        Button("Show the third view.") {
            self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.showNext = true
            }
        }
    }
}
```